# Typecast combobox in java

Tags: java, swing

How do I typecast my defaultListModel?
I want it to hold my objects of type "Account"

Do i need to create a new listmodel that extends listmodel or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Account is a subclass of `Object`, and `DefaultListModel` holds instances of `Object`, so there is no problem. You'll just have to cast the results of the methods (get, getElementAt, etc.) to `Account`:

```
Account a = (Account) listModel.getElementAt(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Java 7 you should be able to do `DefaultListModel<Account>`.

If you're using Java 6 or below and dealing with `Object` is not an issue, you should be able to just put the `Account` instances into your `DefaultListModel` instance. IIRC for displaying `Account` should just have a reasonable `toString()` implementation.